# getting bedmas to work correctly

Tags: java, parsing, operator-precedence, recursive-descent

My code fails when I input something like `3(5)`. 
How do I modify my code so that it solves in expression in the middle and then multiplies?

```
double parseTerm() {
    double x = parseFactor();
    while(true) {
        if      (shift('*')){
            x *= parseFactor(); // multiply
        }
        else if (shift('/')){
            x /= parseFactor(); // divide
        }
        else{
            return x;
        }
    }
}

double parseExpression() {
    double x = parseTerm();
    while(true) {
        if      (shift('+')){
            x += parseTerm(); // addition
        }
        else if (shift('-')){
            x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
        }
        else{
            return x;
        }
    }
}

double parseFactor() {
    if (shift('+')){
        return parseFactor(); //plus
    }
    if (shift('-')){
        return -parseFactor(); //minus
    }

    double x;
    int startPos = this.pos;

    if (shift('(')) { // brackets
        x = parseExpression();
        shift(')');
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with both Java and JavaScript?

Comment: For all those who wonder: [BEDMAS, standing for Brackets, Exponents, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) = order of operations

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - one that is both *minimal* and **complete** - the code above is not complete and I don't think it's minimal either. Then give make your own attempt - and if it doesn't work, show what you tried and what goes wrong in detail. As a hint - if you want an opening parenthesis `(` act as a de-facto multiplication operator, then you need to put something like what you have in the `parseFactor` method for sub expression in the `parseTerm` method as well.

Comment: `3(5)` is not a legal input according to your code. Do you mean `3*(5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you'd need to change in `parseTerm` to get an expression like `3(5)` working the same as `3*(5)`:

```
double parseTerm() {
    double x = parseFactor();
    while(true) {
        if (shift('*')) {
            x *= parseFactor(); // multiply
        } else if (shift('/')) {
            x /= parseFactor(); // divide
        } else if (shift('(')) { // brackets
            x *= parseExpression();
            shift(')');
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

(This is assuming that your `parseFactor` method is correct, because it's incomplete in your code)

Comment: yeah, parseFactor is correct. Couldn't paste it all. Thanks, your solution worked.